# Type callback argument to function based on string literal argument

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to type some functions to get correct types when the function is used, with the minimum of explicit typing at this point of use.  Essentially the function is as follows, and I am aiming to type the `arg` of the callback function dependent on the string passed as the `fntype` argument.

```
fn(fntype: string, callback: (arg: any) => void): void;
```

For example,

```
fn('foo', (foo) => {
    foo.somethingInTheFooInterface;
}

fn('bar', (bar) => {
    bar.somethingInTheBarInterface;
}
```

These are the types I have come up with:

```
type FooType = "FooType";
const FooType: FooType = 'FooType';

type BarType = 'BarType';
const BarType: BarType = 'BarType';

type ActionTypes = FooType | BarType;

interface Action<T> {
    type: T;
}

interface FooInterface extends Action<FooType> {
    somethingOnTheFooInterface: string;
}

interface BarInterface extends Action<BarType> {
    somethingOnTheBarInterface: string;
}

type CallbackTypes = FooInterface | BarInterface;

type Callback<T extends CallbackTypes> = (action: T) => void;

function fn<T extends CallbackTypes, U extends ActionTypes>(actionType: U, cb: Callback<T>): void;

function fn (actionType, cb) {
    cb();
}
```

Which work fine when things are used explicitly:

```
// Works fine if we explicitly type the arg
fn(FooType, (arg: FooInterface) => {
    arg.somethingOnTheFooInterface
});

// Works fine if we define the generics when calling 
fn<FooInterface, FooType>(FooType, arg => {
    arg.somethingOnTheFooInterface;
});
```

But doesn't type the callback based on the first argument:

```
// TypeError as arg is typed as the union type CallbackTypes
fn(FooType, arg => {
    arg.somethingOnTheFooInterface
})
```

If anyone can offer any guidance as to how to achieve this typing then I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Typescript 2.9, and conditional types this is now possible without function overloading:

```
type FooType = "FooType";
const FooType: FooType = "FooType";

type BarType = "BarType";
const BarType: BarType = "BarType";

type ActionTypes = FooType | BarType;

interface Action<T> {
    type: T;
}

interface FooInterface extends Action<FooType> {
    somethingOnTheFooInterface: string;
}

interface BarInterface extends Action<BarType> {
    somethingOnTheBarInterface: string;
}

type CallbackTypes<T> =
    T extends FooType ? FooInterface :
    T extends BarType ? BarInterface :
    never;

type Callback<T> = (action: T) => void;

function fn<T extends ActionTypes, U extends CallbackTypes<T>>(actionType: T, cb: Callback<U>) {
    cb({} as any);
};

fn(FooType, arg => {
    arg.somethingOnTheFooInterface
})

fn(BarType, arg => {
    arg.somethingOnTheBarInterface
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then it seems like a major overkill.
You should be able to achieve your goal with signature overloading:

```
interface FooInterface {
    somethingOnTheFooInterface: string;
}

interface BarInterface {
    somethingOnTheBarInterface: string;
}

fn(fntype: "FooType", callback: (arg: FooInterface) => void): void;
fn(fntype: "BarType", callback: (arg: BarInterface) => void): void;
fn(type: string, callback: (arg: any) => void) { ... }
```